# Is there a probability measure on $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Is there a probability measure on a set whose cardinality is $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ ?

I considered a real-valued stochastic process $S(t),t\in[0,1]$. If $t_0$ is a constant, $S(t_0)$ is an ordinary random variable.

But suppose the set of all sample curves of $S(t)$ is $SC$. We have $Card(SC)=2^{\mathfrak{c}}$.

Let $SP = \{f(t_0)| f\in SC\}$.

I think the probability distribution of random variable $S(t_0)$ should be consistent with the measure of different values in the set $SP$. But $Card(SP)=2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ and the probability measure I know is defined on the set of real numbers.

How to understand the meaning of the set $SP$ and the relationship between $SP$ and $S(t_0)$?

Comment: What are $\mathfrak{c}$ and $SC$?

Comment: @Jfischer. I don't know about $SC$ but I think $|\mathbb{R}|=\mathfrak{c}$

Comment: $\mathfrak{c}$ is continuum. $SC$ is the set of all the sample curve of stochastic process $S(t)$. You can think $SC$ is the set of all the real function $f$ that $f(x)\in[0,1],x\in[0,1]$  .

Comment: For any set $X$ whatsoever, there is a probability measure on $2^X$, namely the product measure obtained from the uniform measure on $2$.